# LuaL_openlibs() and sandboxing scripts

Tags: c++, c, lua

I am embedding Lua (5.1) in a C/C++ application.

I am using the `LuaL_openlibs()` function to load the base libs. However, this function loads some other libraries which I want to disable so that they are not available to my Lua scripts.

Specifically, I want to disable the IO and OS modules. Is there a function I can call to programmativally disable (or unload) these modules so that I can create a safe sandbox environment for running Lua scripts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know how to disable modules, but you can still choose which ones to load instead of loading them all with `luaL_openlibs`. [Section 7.3 of the Lua 5.1 manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.3) says:

> The `luaopen_*` functions (to open libraries) cannot be called directly, like a regular C function. They must be called through Lua, like a Lua function.

That is, instead of directly calling the function as in Lua 5.0:

```
luaopen_table(L);
```

... you push it as a C function with its name and use `lua_call` or similar in Lua 5.1:

```
lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_table);
lua_pushliteral(L, LUA_TABLIBNAME);
lua_call(L, 1, 0);
```

The functions you can do this with are listed in `lualib.h`:

```
Function        | Name
----------------+-----------------
luaopen_base    | ""
luaopen_table   | LUA_TABLIBNAME
luaopen_io      | LUA_IOLIBNAME
luaopen_os      | LUA_OSLIBNAME
luaopen_string  | LUA_STRLIBNAME
luaopen_math    | LUA_MATHLIBNAME
luaopen_debug   | LUA_DBLIBNAME
luaopen_package | LUA_LOADLIBNAME
```

Comment: I should note that this is for lua 5.1, and while it might work with lua 5.2, it's not the recommended way anymore. The best thing is to look in the linit.c file of the lua distribution and see how they do it

Answer (score 18):

`luaL_openlibs` just iterates through a list of library loaders, declared in the same file. Simply delete/comment out the `luaopen_io` and `luaopen_os` lines. Done.

If you're adverse to editing the Lua source, then you can define your own function which leaves out those two libraries:

```
#define LUA_LIB

#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

static const luaL_Reg lualibs[] = {
  {"", luaopen_base},
  {LUA_LOADLIBNAME, luaopen_package},
  {LUA_TABLIBNAME, luaopen_table},
  {LUA_STRLIBNAME, luaopen_string},
  {LUA_MATHLIBNAME, luaopen_math},
  {LUA_DBLIBNAME, luaopen_debug},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

LUALIB_API void my_openlibs (lua_State *L) {
  const luaL_Reg *lib = lualibs;
  for (; lib->func; lib++) {
    lua_pushcfunction(L, lib->func);
    lua_pushstring(L, lib->name);
    lua_call(L, 1, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer (I'm spoilt for choice). Would have voted +1 for this answer (unfortunately, I can't vote!). I had to choose Tung's answer because he answered first with similar info. But I appreciate both answers

Answer (score 9):

The simplest solution of them all: just do `io=nil;os=nil` after loading the libraries.

Comment: That's not enough, the user can require them back ```io=require('io')```

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Lua you used to be able to specify which libraries you wanted to load.  Specifically, in my copy of lualib.h I see the following functions declared:

```
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_base) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_table) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_io) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_os) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_string) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_math) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_debug) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_package) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API void (luaL_openlibs) (lua_State *L);
```

I couldn't tell you the consequences of not loading all the libraries, since I call luaL_openlibs() in my code.  The First Edition of Programming in Lua is available online, and mentions that luaL_openlibs() should replace the luaopen_*() function calls.  However, the older functions may still be included for backwards compatibility. http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Repeating my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57190172/264751) here too.

As of Lua 5.3 you need to `luaL_requiref` these, based on the source code in [luaL_openlibs](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/linit.c.html#luaL_openlibs).  I found no reference to that in any manual.  So here is an example that opens up only the base library which allows lua to `print` to standard output.

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  lua_State *lua = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_requiref( lua, "_G", luaopen_base, 1 );
  lua_pop( lua, 1 );

  luaL_dostring( lua, "print \"Hello, lua\"" );

  lua_close( lua );

  return 0;
}
```

For example you can load only in addition to `base` the I/O library like so.

```
luaL_requiref( lua, LUA_IOLIBNAME, luaopen_io, 1 );
lua_pop( lua, 1 );
```

See also [the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_requiref).

Answer (score 0):

I want to note that the package library should be disabled too.

```lua
package.loadlib("/usr/lib/liblua.so.5.1", "lua_call")()
```

Will load a C function and then call it with incorrect arguments, causing a segfault. This could potentially cause bigger problems than just segfaults