# luaopen functions

Tags: scripting, lua

I found in the lua sample code these calls:

```
luaopen_table(L);
luaopen_io(L);
luaopen_string(L);
luaopen_math(L);
```

I searched in lua header files and I found other functions with luaopen:

```
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_base) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_table) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_io) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_os) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_string) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_math) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_debug) (lua_State *L);
LUALIB_API int (luaopen_package) (lua_State *L);
```

Can you please explain what these functions mean? For example, may I use tables if I don't call luaopen_table? I didn't find any documentation about this!

Comment: Not quite a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551101/lual-openlibs-and-sandboxing-scripts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Lua 5.1, which is the latest version, the [Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5) has an answer :

> To have access to these libraries, the
>   C host program should call the
>   luaL_openlibs function, which opens
>   all standard libraries. Alternatively,
>   it can open them individually by
>   calling luaopen_base (for the basic
>   library), luaopen_package (for the
>   package library), luaopen_string (for
>   the string library), luaopen_table
>   (for the table library), luaopen_math
>   (for the mathematical library),
>   luaopen_io (for the I/O library),
>   luaopen_os (for the Operating System
>   library), and luaopen_debug (for the
>   debug library). These functions are
>   declared in lualib.h and should not be
>   called directly: you must call them
>   like any other Lua C function, e.g.,
>   by using lua_call.

[...]

> The luaopen_* functions (to open
>   libraries) cannot be called directly,
>   like a regular C function. They must
>   be called through Lua, like a Lua
>   function.

And yes, you can still use tables if you don't import the table library, they are built-in. You just don't have access to the [table manipulation functions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.5).

Answer (score 3):

You have to push them onto the stack to call them like you would a normal lua c function.

```
lua_State *l = lua_open();
lua_pushcfunction(l,luaopen_base);
lua_call(l,0,0);
lua_pushcfunction(l,luaopen_math);
lua_call(l,0,0);
lua_pushcfunction(l,luaopen_string);
lua_call(l,0,0);
lua_pushcfunction(l,luaopen_table);
lua_call(l,0,0);
```

Comment: The OP asked two questions, you answered neither and provided sample code of dubious value without explanation. -1

Answer (score 0):

For those who browse this question looking for how to use these functions in modern Lua:

As of Lua 5.3 you need to `luaL_requiref` these, based on the source code in [luaL_openlibs](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/linit.c.html#luaL_openlibs).  I found no reference to that in any manual.  So here is an example that opens up only the base library which allows lua to `print` to standard output.

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  lua_State *lua = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_requiref( lua, "_G", luaopen_base, 1 );
  lua_pop( lua, 1 );

  luaL_dostring( lua, "print \"Hello, lua\"" );

  lua_close( lua );

  return 0;
}
```

I cannot say what exactly all these libraries mean, nor how not loading them will affect you, but you can load them individually with the example given above.  For example,

```
luaL_requiref( lua, LUA_IOLIBNAME, luaopen_io, 1 );
lua_pop( lua, 1 );
```

would load only the I/O library.  See also [the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_requiref).